# Magento with Mailchimp -----adding checkboxes programmatically

Tags: magento, mailchimp

I have just created a mailchimp account and I have one question. I'm quite new to mailchimp.

In my customer dashboard (of magento) i want to create a list subscribe form. Now I have a list of checkboxes that i run using a for next loop. I want to put these checkboxes in my mailchimp form and according to what the customer choices, the mailchimp list is updated.

Ex. I have various categories (Apparel, furniture etc) these are set up from Magento backend and they have to be dynamic. These checkboxes are set up in a table.

In Mailchimp I want to create user lists or one list with a group containing sub categories, that are created by my Magento code.

I was wondering if this is possible. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Regards,

Luke

Comment: Sorry my question from you :) Have you created list in MailChimp by code. If yes then can you please help in creating the list. I am also now to the MailChimp....

Answer (score 0):

I think you can possibly do this, using the MailChimp API Code. I haven't tried it myself, but I think that is how it is done.